# How to render ruby code inside Coffescript .js.coffee

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, coffeescript

I trying to render a partial when click on select list.

Why this render the partial file without problem:

users/index.html :

```
 <%= select_tag :priority, options_for_select([['low'],
                                               ['normal'],
                                               ['high'],
                                               ['critical']]),             
                data: {form: escape_javascript(render(:partial => "my_partial_file"))}
 
 %>

<div id="div_teste">
    CHANGE IT!
</div>
```

assets/javascript/user.js :

```
$ ->
    $('#priority').change ->
        $('#div_test').html($('#priority').data('form'))
```

But if I try this code:

```
$ ->
    $('#priority').change ->
        my_data = "<%= j render my_partial_file %>"
        $('#div_test').html(my_data)
```

It just render pure text and not the partial file:

## <%= j render my_partial_file %>

Answer (score 2):

Your index page is rendered with each page request.  Your assets are rendered once, likely ahead of time.  Putting request data into an asset wouldn't make sense.

If you want to feed data from your application into your pre-processed coffee/javascript, use [data attributes](http://ejohn.org/blog/html-5-data-attributes/).

Here's a [RailsCast on the topic](http://railscasts.com/episodes/324-passing-data-to-javascript).

Comment: While I agree with Nick, if you ever need to use ERB within a JS file you could add the erb extension then you can use ERB tags in it. Eg your user.js would be user.js.coffee.erb

See http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html 
2.3.3 JavaScript/CoffeeScript and ERB

Comment: I've never done that, I assume that's still going to restrict the use of ERB to methods callable without any request or state, right?  Like URL helpers and stuff?  Or can the asset pipeline be invoked on every request?  That seems like it would be a very bad idea.

Comment: I used this a few times only when I had to use a rails url helper in JS. Other use case could be to use an app wide configuration in JS. In dev mode it does not matter. In production mode it gets evaluated only when you precompile your assets, so that limits it's usage anyway.